# GeocoderUnavailable: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: python, geopy

I am currently trying to start working with geopy but I just can't get through a certification error:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="autenticador")

full_address = 'AVENIDA EDSON RAMALHO, 122, 58030100, JOAO PESSOA'

location = geolocator.geocode(full_address)

location
```

error message>

```
GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=AVENIDA+EDSON+RAMALHO%2C+122%2C+58030100%2C+JOAO+PESSOA&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: Are you inside a corporate or school network which has SSL interception turned on? An easy way to check this is to visit https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ in a browser, click on the lock, click on view certificate, and check if the certificate is issued by Let's Encrypt or someone else.

Comment: [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74901355/my-geopy-geocoders-is-throwing-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-how-can-i) a same question. And [here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests) solutions how to disable certificate checks